# Smooth scrolling layout when keyboard comes up?

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

Currently, when an EditText comes into focus and the keyboard comes up, the keyboard covers the form layout for a second, then the layout container resizes to expose the form, as illustrated below.

[image]

I'd like the layout to resize smoothly as the keyboard rises up. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Excuse me, could you tell me where I can find the app you drew the mockups?

Comment: @LaiVung It's OmniGraffle for OSX: http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/ The phone image is from Google's OmniGraffle stencil: http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

Comment: Thank you  :-) Unfortunately I don't use Mac. (*If you don't mind, [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html) is free and good*).

Comment: @LaiVung No problem. :) OmniGraffle is pretty much the standard for UX people here in Silicon Valley, as far as I have seen in my career. The strength is in the number of user-created stencil templates on the web. This is a good site for these stencils: https://www.graffletopia.com/

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your  in the manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible"
```

Comment: Do you have a <requestfocus/> tag in the layout? Please post the activity code, layout xml and manifest snippets.